# Transfer branch from old repository to new

Tags: git, github

So there is a project in old repository that is currently on production. We are doing some major changes to app deploy pipelines so I want to create new repositories for frontend, backend and admin codebases and connect them to heroku and we are going to switch to those repositories soon. On old codebases main branch is called `master`, there is also development branch, but dev branch is currently same as master for every codebase so it is not important. I want to transfer code from master branch to new repositories main branch. Other branches are not important so they don't need to be moved.

My idea would be to add new remote `git remote add newremote newrepo.git` and after that while on master do `git push newremote master:main`.

Is this proper way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works. You can also do the other direction, adding the old repo as remote to the new one and then `git fetch`ing the branches you need. (That would be my way of doing it).

In fact, you don't need to add the remote at all. `push` and `fetch` can work with URLs directly.